# Should you ever update your database in an Ajax call?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm running into an issue of where I would like to update a database *after* an ajax call has been fully made. In order to find the value that I want to update the database with I have to make a SOAP call (or server request) which take some time. I'd like to instead use the value that was found in that ajax call and then store that in my database.

Here is my ajax call

```
 <script>
function getBalance(){
    $.get("assets/balance.php", "", function(data){
        // # means an id, but a . would mean a class
        // .html means replace the html of id with the balance 
        $('#balance').html(data);
        // alert(data);
    });
}
getBalance();

</script>
```

and here is the balance.php that is being called

```
    /**
*@method CheckBalance() : this  method helps to get the balance info of the tigo cash subscriber using tigo rwanda middleware
*@param string  $msisdn : this is the mobile number of the tigo cash subscriber
*@param string $pin    : this is the pin number of the tigo cash account 
*@return returns the decoded answer either as the balance (int) or a warning (string)
*/
function BalanceCall($msisdn,$pin){

  //Store your XML Request in a variable
    $input_xml = 


.... some xml .... 

// url of the server the request is going to  
$url = "http://10.138.84.138:8002/osb/services/GetBalance_1_0";



// returns a long xml string reply
$xmlstring = curl_exec($soap_do);

// this returns either the balance (int) or an error (string)
return $result = Helpers::decodeBalanceString($xmlstring);
}
```

Now would it be appropriate to then update my database from within balance.php? I'd like to keep my database updated - and I don't know a way to call a function like " updatDatabase" i in the controller after the render because it will JS run before the java script function finishes.

Comment: Yes its quite common to perform database updates/inserts when provessing ajax requests on the server.

Comment: Really? Is there any fear that someone might have javascript disabled? (My only fear is that I am now sudo updating my database from the view)

Comment: @Stephen Look into "graceful degradation", or do what virtually every modern startup does and just require JS. You're no more "updating my database from the view" than a `<form>` tag in a view is.

Comment: It's only as dangerous as a form input. Just don't use some value that a user could alter if it will adversely effect your database, in case the JavaScript gets hacked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well technically speaking you can't update the DB in the AJAX call...  your AJAX call fires code and an AJAX call is not much different at all than any other HTTP method.  I mean it is a HTTP call... so of course it is perfectly fine to update the DB if the code being fired is a result of an AJAX call.

Comment: Is there any fear that someone might have javascript disabled? As I said in the previous comment, I'm a bit concerned about updating my database from a call I make in the view? (it seems like I'm breaking down MVC at that point)

Comment: If javascript is disabled, the ajax call will never happen, so it's pretty safe.

Comment: are you send SQL from your JS?  You should be firing methods and your calls should be validated from a security pers etc...

Comment: Right but if I am basing my database being updated upon the fact that that the ajax call is being made then wouldn't my database NOT update?

Comment: In this situation I am making a request to a remote server - let me update the code to show this

Comment: if js is disabled then a lot of sites won't work... lol.... it's a pretty common requirement.

Comment: you shouldn't worry too much about compatibility, only very little portion will have js disabled (and 99% of them are bots), eg. you are unlikely going to support IE6/7 right?

Comment: Okay, so you think that it I should just put a warning that if jscript is disabled say "YO. Enable Javascript"